# Question involving partial derivatives and matrix representations

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, jacobian

The question says:

> Assume that $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ and $g: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ are differentiable and $h: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, $h(x,y)=f(x,y,g(x,y))$.
>
> (a) Write D$h(x,y)$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$.
>
> (b) Suppose that $h(x,y)=0$ $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$. Write $\frac {\partial g} {\partial x}(x,y)$ and $\frac {\partial g} {\partial y}(x,y)$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$ at the point $(x,y,g(x,y))$.

EDIT: I think I have figured out part (a)... but now I'm stuck with part (b). Can't find a way to write $\frac {\partial g} {\partial x}(x,y)$ and $\frac {\partial g} {\partial y}(x,y)$ or find out what difference it makes that $h(x,y)=0$. If anybody has any hints on how to approach part (b), please help me! Thanks

Comment: Consider $j : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that $j(x,y) = (x,y,g(x,y))$, then $h = f \circ j$, and so ${\rm D}h(x,y)$ is the matrix product ${\rm D}f(j(x,y)) {\rm D}j(x,y)$. Note that ${\rm D}f(u,v,w)$ is the gradient of $f$ at $(u,v,w)$ (which is a $1 \times 3$ matrix) and that ${\rm D}j(x,y)$ is a $3 \times 2$ matrix. Can you continue from here?

Comment: @azif00 Not really... I'm still confused about what's going on here

Comment: Given a differentiable function $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, assume $F(x) = (F_1(x),\dots,F_m(x))$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Then the derivative of $F$ at $a \in \mathbb R^n$ is the $m \times n$ matrix ${\rm D}F(a)$ whose $i$-th row looks like $$\Big( \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_1}(a) \ \cdots \ \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_n}(a) \Big).$$

Comment: @azif00 Okay, so let's see if I got this right... We have the function $f(u, v, w)$ with three coordinates. First, we want to find D$f(j(x,y))$, which is the derivative of $f(u, v, w)$ at the point $j(x,y)=(x,y,g(x,y))$.
The matrix form of D$f(j(x,y))$ is a 1x3 matrix, so 

D$f(j(x,y))=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac {\partial f}{\partial u}(j(x,y)) & \frac {\partial f}{\partial v}(j(x,y)) & \frac {\partial f}{\partial w}(j(x,y))  \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Is it correct?

Comment: @azif00 And D$j(x,y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac {\partial j}{\partial x}(x,y) & \frac {\partial j}{\partial y}(x,y) \\
c & d \\
e & f
\end{bmatrix}$

And then I just multiply both matrices to get D$h(x,y)$? (NOTE I wrote c, d, e, and f bc I'm not sure how to write those other 4 terms).

Comment: Yes, you've write ${\rm D}f(j(x,y))$ in the correct way. Also, so that you do not get confused any more, I suggest that you do not introduce new symbols: write $\partial_jf$ for the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to the $j$-th coordinate. Thus ${\rm D}f(u,v,w) = \big( \partial_1f(u,v,w) \ \ \partial_2f(u,v,w) \ \ \partial_3f(u,v,w) \big)$.

Comment: (cont.) Keep in mind that the partial derivative only makes sense (at least for now) for functions into $\mathbb R$. For a more general function $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ you have that ${\rm D}F(a)$ is the $m \times n$ matrix whose $i$-th row is ${\rm D}F_i(a)$, where $F_i : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is the $i$-th component function of $F$.

Comment: @azif00 Using the notation you suggested, $j(x,y)=(j_1, j_2, j_3)$ and $\partial_1j_1(x,y)=\frac{\partial j_1}{\partial x}$? So the D$j(x,y)$ matrix would be

D$j(x,y)=
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_1 j_1(x,y) & \partial_2 j_1(x,y) \\
\partial_1 j_2(x,y) & \partial_2 j_2(x,y) \\
\partial_1 j_3(x,y) & \partial_2 j_3(x,y)
\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: That's right: $(x,y,g(x,y)) = j(x,y) = (j_1(x,y),j_2(x,y),j_3(x,y))$, so $j_1(x,y)=x$, $j_2(x,y) = y$ and $j_3(x,y) = g(x,y)$.

Comment: @azif00 Well I think I'm done with part (a)... now any hints for part (b)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, let's say $F(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \big( F_1(x_1,\dots,x_n), \dots, F_m(x_1,\dots,x_n) \big)$, is a differentiable function, the derivative of $F$ at a point $a \in \mathbb R^n$ is the $m \times n$ matrix ${\rm D}F(a)$ whose $i$-th row contains all the partial derivatives of $F_i$ at $a$, that is, the $i$-th row of ${\rm D}F(a)$ is $$\big[ \partial_1F_i(a) \ \ \cdots \ \ \partial_nF_i(a) \big].$$ In your case, if you write $h$ as $f \circ j$, where $j : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$ is the function $j(x,y) = (x,y,g(x,y))$, by the chain rule you have $$\begin{align} {\rm D}h(x,y) &= {\rm D}f(j(x,y)) {\rm D}j(x,y) \\ &= \begin{bmatrix} \partial_1f(j(x,y)) & \partial_2f(j(x,y)) & \partial_3f(j(x,y)) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&1 \\ \partial_1g(x,y) & \partial_2g(x,y) \end{bmatrix} \\ &= \begin{bmatrix} \partial_1f(j(x,y)) + \partial_3f(j(x,y)) \partial_1g(x,y) & \partial_2f(j(x,y)) + \partial_3f(j(x,y)) \partial_2g(x,y) \end{bmatrix}. \end{align}$$
So, if $h=0$, $$\begin{align} {\rm D}h(x,y)=[0 \quad 0] &\implies \begin{cases} \partial_1f(j(x,y)) + \partial_3f(j(x,y)) \partial_1g(x,y) = 0 \\ \partial_2f(j(x,y)) + \partial_3f(j(x,y)) \partial_2g(x,y) = 0 \end{cases} \\[1mm] &\implies \begin{cases}  \partial_1g(x,y) = - \dfrac{\partial_1f(j(x,y))}{\partial_3f(j(x,y))} \\ \partial_2g(x,y) = - \dfrac{\partial_1f(j(x,y))}{\partial_3f(j(x,y))} \end{cases} \end{align}$$

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I was on the right path but wasn't very sure if what i was doing was correct haha. Now, do we have to assume that $\partial_3 f(j(x,y)) \neq 0$ or is this already implicitly stated on the condition that $h(x,y)=0$?